# When using Process.Start(), how can I keep the cmd prompt open for the duration of the program?

Tags: c#, selenium-rc

Right now I'm trying to use C# to open wither a .java server, or a .bat file that launched the same server. I am able to launch it fine, however if quickly closes since the single command I wanted to perform executed. The problem is I need to keep the cmd window open in order to keep the server up.

I have a few different version of how I want to start the process, this being the shortest one to post:

```
Process seleniumServer;
ProcessStartInfo seleniumServerProcessStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("java", @"C:\Users\full\path\to\file\selenium-server.jar");
Process.Start(seleniumServerProcessStartInfo);
```

How can I make sure the cmd window that popups which launches the selenium-server.jar file keeps open until the program closes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Launch it with "-jar foo.jar" as args, like:

```
ProcessStartInfo seleniumServerProcessStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("java", @"-jar C:\Users\full\path\to\file\selenium-server.jar");
```

The window is probably disappearing because the jar never gets launched.

Answer (score 4):

You can run `cmd /C your-command` instead, which keeps command line open.

Comment: Pretty sure you meant /K, since /C is the opposite (k for keep, c for close).

Comment: multiple stackoverflow posts and this is the first one to explain the difference between /C and /K, thanks comrade!

Answer (score 1):

Use [Process.WaitForExit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty0d8k56.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Might be that the java process stops with an error (it can be picky on the environment vars)

```
    Process selenium = Process.Start(seleniumServerProcessStartInfo); 

    selenium.WaitForExit();

    int exit = selenium.ExitCode;

    if (exit!=0)
       throw new Exception("java selenium server stopped with error");
```